# Parse nested queries: inner query never excutes

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I'm trying to loop all buses and update their information by querying another class called bus stop. What I did is something like this:

```
busQuery.each(function(bus){
  var busRouteQuery = new Parse.Query("busRoute");
  busRouteQuery.find({
    //retrieve data from bus stop and update bus location
    success: function(results){
    },
    error: function(){
    }
  });
});
```

However, the inner busRouteQuery is never called. any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you might be using an old version of the JavaScript SDK for Parse. Is this cloud code? From the guide:

"The default Parse JavaScript SDK version that is used for the Cloud Code in this directory is the latest version at the time the new command was run for this directory. If you want to change this, you can change the parseVersion in config/global.json."

https://parse.com/docs/cloud_code_guide#clt-version

Comment: Yes, I was using old version of JS SDK. I think the functions are asynchronous, so it finishes the outer query first and then executes inner query. that is why outer function response success already but inner query is never executed. Thanks for your help.